# sava data in mat file in matlab issues

Tags: matlab

For my project I want to save a variable in mat file. Here is my code.

```
s1 = [1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10];
for fr = 1 : 1 :10
    data_file = [];
    save('/home/shahnawaz/Desktop/yaml/YAMLMatlab_0.4.3/mytest.mat','s1')
    data_file = s1(:)';
    save('/home/shahnawaz/Desktop/yaml/YAMLMatlab_0.4.3/mytest.mat','s1','-append')
end
```

**Problem**
I want to save 10 instances of s1 in mat file. Can some one help me how I can do that.

Comment: You cannot have multiple variables with the same name in a mat-file. They get simply overwritten. The `'append'`-property is used to append to the file instead of overwriting it. In this case, `s1` gets overwritten while other variables in the mat-file stay untouched.

Comment: You cannot save 10 variable with a similar name in a matlab file. Either give 10 different names to a copy of the original variable and save these, or replicate your original variable 10 times and save the big one.

Comment: that's what I know already. Is there any way around?

Comment: what do you mean by satisfied with a different structure of the data stored? sorry I didn't get it.

Comment: Let's say a cell-array. That would be a single variable named `s1` with each cell representing the data of an iteration.

Comment: I normally different structure of the data.  That's just an example that I quote

Comment: i want to do like that `s1 1xaaaa cell s1 1xaaa cell ......`

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What is the benefit? How you want to load the data in the workspace later?

Comment: you are right. I can't do that so I need to s1, s2, s3 and so on. Otherwise I won't be able to load the data from the mat file at the later stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your comment on the question, here is a solution that stores the variables as `s1`, `s2`, ... directly from the loop without explicitly writing them in your code. An intermediate struct is used to store the variables until they get saved to the `.mat`-file.

```
for i = 1:5
    data.(['s',num2str(i)]) = 10*i;
end

save('mytest.mat','-struct','data')
```

---

*The content of the `.mat`-file looks as follows:*

```
>> whos -file mytest.mat

  Name      Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

  s1        1x1                 8  double                          
  s2        1x1                 8  double              
  s3        1x1                 8  double              
  s4        1x1                 8  double              
  s5        1x1                 8  double
```